# SwiftUI animation not continuous after view change

Tags: animation, swiftui

Here is the testing code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var pad: Bool = false
  @State private var showDot: Bool = true
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button {showDot.toggle()} label: {Text("Toggle Show Dot")}
      Spacer().frame(height: pad ? 100 : 10)
      Circ(showDot: showDot)
      Spacer()
    }.onAppear {
      withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3).repeatForever()) {pad = true}
    }
  }
}

struct Circ: View {
  let showDot: Bool
  var body: some View {
    Circle().stroke().frame(height: 50).overlay {if showDot {Circle().frame(height: 20)}}
  }
}
```

It happens that after I toggle `showDot`, the dot circle is not on the center of the stroke circle again! How can I fix this?
The `Circ` View is given, I can't change that view!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

If you can just hide the view, see solution 1, which is preferred. If you need to re-build the view, see solution 2.

**Solution 1**

Replace the `if` condition with a `.opacity()` modifier that reads 1 when `showDot` is `true`.

This way, the dot does not disappear completely, it is there but you just can't see it. You will be toggling the visibility, not the view itself.

Like this:

```
    @State private var pad: Bool = false
    @State private var showDot: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                showDot.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Toggle Show Dot")
            }
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: pad ? 100 : 10)
            
            Circle().stroke()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .overlay {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(height: 20)
                        .opacity(showDot ? 1 : 0)   // <- Here
                }
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3).repeatForever()) {pad = true}
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2**

You can replace the animation with a timer. Every time it triggers, it will move the whole view by changing the height of the `Spacer()`.

```
    
    // These variables will track the position and moving direction of the dot
    @State private var pos: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var movingUp = false
    
    @State private var showDot: Bool = true
    
    // This variable will change the position
    // This is a dummy iniatialization, the .onAppear modifier sets the real timer
    @State private var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in }
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                showDot.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Toggle Show Dot")
            }
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: pos)

            Circle().stroke()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .overlay {
                    if showDot {
                        Circle().frame(height: 20)
                    }
                }
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            // The timer interval will define the speed
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true) { _ in
                moveCircle()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func moveCircle() {
        if movingUp {
            if pos <= 0 {
                pos = 0
                movingUp = false
            } else {
                pos -= 1
            }
        } else {
            if pos >= 100 {
                pos = 100
                movingUp = true
            } else {
                pos += 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my real situation, when `showDot == false`, I can't get the "Dot View". Hence the opacity method can't apply.

Comment: @蘇哲聖, animation is applied to existed views, if you remove view and then insert new one (because it is new one) the running animation is not applied to it, you have to stop running animation and restart it again to apply to new view. So this is the only solution for scenario described in original question... Or you need to update your question with more accurate description of what's really needed in your app.

Comment: @蘇哲聖: see edited solution, if it works for you.

Comment: The timer method works. Thank you!